# Connect to an external Oracle database using JDBC

Tags: oracle, spring, jdbc, cloud-foundry

I've setup a Spring project that access a remote Oracle database but only if I run this Spring project on my local Tomcat. If I deploy it to CF either as JavaWeb or Spring project I always get the same error message:

> root cause
>
> org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException:
>   Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   **org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection**
>     org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:3
>   ....

This is my config:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource">
    <property name="driverType">
        <value>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</value>
    </property>
    <property name="URL">
        <value>${jdbc.url}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="user">
        <value>${jdbc.username}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">
        <value>${jdbc.password}</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" p:dataSource-ref="dataSource">
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" p:showSql="true"
              p:generateDdl="true">
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <value>
            hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
            hibernate.dialect=${hibernate.dialect}
            hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I've tried to use oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver instead of oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver. I've tried to use `<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"...`,  with corresponding property names. Also I've tried:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SingleConnectionDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName">
        <value>${database.driverClassName}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="url">
        <value>${jdbc.url}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="username">
        <value>${jdbc.username}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">
        <value>${jdbc.password}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suppressClose" value="true"/>
    <property name="autoCommit" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

and

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName">
        <value>${database.driverClassName}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="url">
        <value>${jdbc.url}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="username">
        <value>${jdbc.username}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">
        <value>${jdbc.password}</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Nothing worked, I get always the same error.

I've tried to use HSQL with this config

and these jdbc.properties:

```
# HSQL
database.driverClassName = org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
#jdbc.url = jdbc:hsqldb:file:target/zktodo2test.dat
jdbc.url = jdbc:hsqldb:file:zktodo2test.dat
jdbc.username = sa
jdbc.password =

hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = update
```

...and **it worked** but when using these jdbc.properties:

```
# Oracle Credentials
database.driverClassName = oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
jdbc.url = jdbc:oracle:thin:@dev.example.com:1521:dev
jdbc.username = epvin
jdbc.password = my_password

hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = update
```

I get the error mentioned above.

Comment: Did you confirm by printing the data source properties with log level for spring package set to debug, to see if the login/password are replaced properly?

Comment: In your case always deploy the app as JavaWeb instead of Spring, for the latter will re-write the datasource properties. You should be aware of the doc here: http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/frameworks/java/spring/spring.html. As Vikdor asked, it would be a good idea to print out the values of these properties.

Comment: I've replaced ${jdbc.values} by actual values. So the values should be correct. Also I've added the missing directives from the page William gave me. Still the same error.

Comment: Hey, replacing with the actual value will not help. The property values will be re-configured by CF. To be more specific, you might want to read the doc of this section: http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/frameworks/java/spring/spring.html#determining-whether-your-application-can-be-auto-configured

Answer (score 2):

It is a weird Oracle-specific authentication issue. Authenticating to a MySQL service running  on the same server works fine.

Comment: Hey, in that case would you try deploying to your local server and connect to the same Orcacle data source to have a test?